# Problem 6 - IMO 1985

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, contest-math

For every real number $x_1$ construct the sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots$ by setting $x_{n+1}=x_n(x_n+\frac{1}{n})$ for each $n \ge 1$. Prove that there exists exactly one value of $x_1$ for which $0 < x_n < x_{n+1} < 1$ for every $n$.

Comment: Solution here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=366601&sid=023d45a64cad8c2c050e593bf0ac3971#p366601

Comment: I think this proof is very artificial... I want to work in a more simple solution...

Comment: Nice question! Any chance you can tell us what that value of $x_1$ is?

Comment: @boywholived: Thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos: See my too long comment ("answer") below for a numerical approximation of $x_1$.

Comment: @boywholived: You say you "have mentioned the procedure to find $x_1$". I don't quite get it, though. Does that result in (approximately) the same algorithm as given [below](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759599/problem-6-imo-1985/858781#858781) ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assume that there is some $x_1$ such that $0<x_n<x_{n+1}<1$ then $\{x_n\}$ is monotonically increasing and bounded. Hence converges by [monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).

Let $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}{x_n}=l$, then obtain $l^2=l \Rightarrow l=0,1$, we can readily omit $0$ and hence $x_n\rightarrow 1$.

---

**Proof for *uniqueness*** of $x_1$.

Assume for the first term $x_1$ and $a_1$, the sequence $\{x_n\}$ and $\{a_n\}$ converges. Without loss of generality assume $x_1>a_1$(Recall that the definition states that all terms of the sequence are positive). Using induction we can prove that $x_n>a_n \quad\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

As $x_n$ and $a_n$ both converges to $1$, there exits an $N$ such that for all $n\ge N\implies \frac{3}{4}<a_n<x_n<1 $ (Take $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{4}$)

Observe that $$x_{n+1}-a_{n+1}=\left(x_n-a_n\right)\left(x_n+a_n\right)+\frac{1}{n}\left(x_n-a_n\right)>\frac{3}{2}(x_n-a_n)$$

Hence $$\begin{array}{rcl}\frac{x_{n+1}-a_{n+1}}{x_n-a_n}&>&\frac{3}{2}\implies\\
x_{n+1}-a_{n+1}&>&\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n+1-N}\cdot(x_N-a_N) \\ \end{array}$$

The divergence of $x_n-a_n$ is clear. A contradiction.

---

**To prove the *existence***, denote $f_{1}(x)=x$ and $f_{n+1}(x)=f_{n}(x)\left(f_{n}(x)+\frac{1}{n}\right)$. Using induction prove that $f_{n}(x)$ is a *strictly increasing* function in $x$.

Let $b_n$, $c_n$ be such that $f_{n}(b_n)=1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $f_{n}(c_n)=1$, the existence and uniqueness of $b_n$, $c_n$ follows from monotonicity of $f_n$, the observations $f_{n}(0)=0$, $f_{n}(1)>1$ and the continuity of $f_{n}$. Also observe that $b_n<c_n$ and using induction that $b_n$ is *strictly increasing* and $c_n$ is *strictly decreasing* sequences.

The set $A=\{b_n\}$ is bounded above. Hence by [least upper bound property of $\mathbb{R}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property) there exists a $\gamma =\sup \{b_n\}$. We shall show that $\gamma$ is indeed our $x_1$!

$$\color{blue}{f_{n+1}{(\gamma)}}=f_{n}(\gamma)\left(f_n{(\gamma)}+\frac{1}{n}\right)\color{blue}{>}f_{n}(\gamma)\left(f_{n}(b_n)+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\color{blue}{f_{n}(\gamma)>0}$$
$$\color{blue}{1}=f_{n}(c_{n})\color{blue}{>f_{n}(\gamma)} \quad \forall n $$ $$\implies 1>f_{n+1}{(\gamma)}>f_{n}(\gamma)>0 \qquad \square$$

---

**Proofs of interest**

$f_n(x)$ has non negative integer coefficients hence $f_n(x)$ is *strictly increasing* on $[0,1]$.

Notice that $\color{blue}{f_{n+1}(b_n)}=f_{n}(b_n)\left(f_{n}(b_n)+\frac{1}{n}\right)=1-\frac{1}{n}\color{blue}{<}1-\frac{1}{n+1}=\color{blue}{f_{n+1}(b_{n+1})} \implies b_n< b_{n+1}$ or $b_n$ is a *strictly increasing* sequence.

Notice that $\color{blue}{f_{n+1}(c_n)}=f_{n}(c_n)\left(f_{n}(c_n)+\frac{1}{n}\right)=1+\frac{1}{n}\color{blue}{>}1=\color{blue}{f_{n+1}(c_{n+1})} \implies c_{n+1}<c_n$ or $c_n$ is a *strictly decreasing* sequence.

The fact that $b_n$ is bounded is clear as $b_n<c_1 \quad \forall n$.

Comment: How is the sequence  bounded? That depends on $x_1$, which is yet to be determined! For example $x_1>\frac{\sqrt 5-1}2$ leads to $x_2>1$ and from then on the sequnce diverges exponentially. - And monotonic depends on the choiice of $x_1$ as well. - Finally, I seem to have missed your definitions of $a_n, b_n$.

Comment: @boywholived: I've withdrawn my downvote, but still find your proof as a whole not very convincing. Which may be due to my own dyslexia.

Comment: Check, check, double check .. Upon repeatedly re-reading your purported proof,  I couldn't detect any serious flaw in it. Therefore I've removed the question mark in my answer and the accompanying comment. I always have an uneasy feeling,
though, with such abstract _non-constructive_ proofs establishing existence and uniqueness, without actually calculating the number in question. Therefore, in
my own too long comment, I've "replaced" existence by explicit calculation and uniqueness by error analysis. Thus trying to fill that gap.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a separate answer, but rather a (too long) comment in response to
the proper answer by
[boywholived](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/63095/boywholived).
Sure, there exists exactly one such value of $x_1$, but the comment by
[barak manos](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/131263/barak-manos)
still stands: *any chance you can tell us what that value of $x_1$ is?* Here is a little computer program that does the job:

```
program IMO_1985;

procedure find;
const
  LARGE : integer = 50;
var
  n,i : integer;
  x,x_1,bit : double;
  H,L : boolean;
begin
{ Initialize }
  x_1 := 1/2;
  bit := 1/2;
  for i := 0 to LARGE do
  begin
    n := 1;
    H := true;
    L := true;
  { Writeln(n:2,' : ',x_1); }
    x := x_1;
    while true do
    begin
      x := x*(x+1/n);
    { Writeln((n+1):2,' : ',x); }
    { Decreasing towards zero: }
      L := (x < 1-1/n);
    { Exploding towards infinity: }
      H := (x > 1);
      if H or L then Break;
      n := n+1;
    end;
  { Readln; }
  { Find x_1 bit by bit: }
    bit := bit/2;
    if H then x_1 := x_1 - bit;
    if L then x_1 := x_1 + bit;
  end;
  Writeln(x_1:0:16);
end;

begin
  find;
end.
```

The program uses a few easy to prove statements about the sequence:

- If the sequence $x_n$ is decreasing for some value of $n$ ( $x_{n+1} < x_n$ ) then it
  will remain that way until it reaches a limit, which is zero.
- The sequence is decreasing if and only if $x_n < 1-1/n$ . Due
  to the previous statement, we can put a Break in the calculations
  then. And conclude that our estimate of the initial value $x_1$
  must have been greater (by one bit).
- If some value of $x_n$ becomes greater than $1$ then the sequence
  will be increasing forever (i.e. it explodes). We can put a Break in
  the calculations then. And conclude that our estimate of the initial
  value $x_1$ must have been smaller (by one bit).

It turns out that the convergence of the sequence towards the desired
limit $\;x_n \to 1\;$ is *extremely unstable* numerically. So what we actually 
have is a switch between $\,0\,$ and $\,\infty\,$ that generates the outcome
for $x_1$ bit by bit, until double precision is reached.
 Now I almost forgot to tell you what **the outcome is**:
$$
   x_1 \approx 0.4465349172642295
$$
**Reverse method.**
If a method is (numerically) unstable, then try the reverse.
Because it's not uncommon that the latter will be stable then.
So let's solve $x_n \ge 0$ from $x_{n+1} = x_n(x_n+1/n)$:
$$
x_n^2 + \frac{1}{n} x_n - x_{n+1} = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad
x_n = -\frac{1}{2n}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2+x_{n+1}}
= \frac{x_{n+1}}{\frac{1}{2n}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^2+x_{n+1}}}
$$
The latter trick is for reasons of numerical stability as well.
Now start with some LARGE value of $n$ and put $x_{n+1}=1-1/(n+1)$.
Then iterate backwards until $x_1$ is reached.
The resulting (Pascal) program has been an almost one-liner (i.e. without the Error Analysis):

```
program IMO_1985;

procedure find;
const
  LARGE : integer = 50;
var
  n : integer;
  x,E : Extended;
begin
{ Initialize }
  x := 1-1/(LARGE+1);
  E := 1/(LARGE+1);
  for n := LARGE downto 1 do
  begin
    x := x/(sqrt(1/sqr(2*n)+x)+1/(2*n));
  { Error Analysis: }
    E := E/(2*x+1/n);
  end;
  Writeln('Outcome x_1 = ',x:0:16);
  Writeln(' # decimals = ',-Trunc(ln(E)/ln(10)));
  Writeln('# good bits = ',-Trunc(ln(E)/ln(2)));
end;

begin
  find;
end.
```

Needless to say that the outcome is the same as with the previous method.

**Error Analysis.** Estimate with infinitesimals:
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n(x_n+1/n) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad dx_{n+1} = (2x_n+1/n)dx_n
$$
Initialize with $\;dx_{n+1} = 1/(n+1)$ . It follows that:
$$
dx_1 = \frac{dx_{n+1}}{(2x_1+1)(2x_2+1/2)(2x_3+1/3)\cdots(2x_n+1/n)}
$$
The *Reverse method* program has been slightly modified to take this
into account. The variable E corresponds with the errors $dx_n$ .
Minus the 10-logarithm of the error $dx_1$ in $x_1$ is the number of significant decimals, $16$ in our case, which indeed seems to be alright. Minus the 2-logarithm of the error $dx_1$ in $x_1$ is the number of significant bits: $53$ .
This number, not at all by coincidence (why?), is close to the number LARGE $=50$
in both programs.

**Update.**
 Actually, our value $\,x_1\,$ as well as the error $\,dx_1\,$ are functions of $\,n$ , so let's replace $\,x_1\,$ by $\,X(n)\,$ for all finite values of $\,n\,$ and likewise $\,dx_1\,$ by $\,\epsilon(n)$ :
$$
\epsilon(n) = \frac{1/(n+1)}{(2x_1+1)(2x_2+1/2)(2x_3+1/3)\cdots(2x_n+1/n)}
\quad \Longrightarrow \\
\epsilon(n) = \epsilon(n-1)\frac{n/(n+1)}{2x_n+1/n}
$$
With $\,1-1/n < x_n < 1\,$ we have $\,2-1/n < 2x_n+1/n < 2+1/n\,$ and:
$$
\epsilon(n) < \epsilon(n-1)\frac{1}{(1+1/n)(2-1/n)} = \frac{1}{2+1/n-1/n^2} < \frac{1}{2}
\quad \Longrightarrow \quad
\epsilon(n) < \epsilon(1)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}
$$
For $\,n=1\,$ we have $\,1 < 2x_1+1 < 3\,$ hence $\,\epsilon(1) < 1/2$ . This proves a
**Lemma.** (see above: so that's why!) :
$$
\epsilon(n) < \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n
$$
*Note*. I'm not quite sure of this, because $\,\epsilon(1)=dx_1=1/2\,$ is not an infinitesimal ( i.e sufficiently small ) error; perhaps $\,\epsilon(n)\,$ must be multiplied with a proper constant?
**Theorem.** As expected:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} X(n) = x_1
$$
**Proof.** For all real $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an integer $N > 0$
such that if $n > N$ then $\left|X(n) - x_1\right| < \epsilon$ .
Indeed, define $N$ by $\,N = \ln(1/\epsilon)/\ln(2)$ , then $\,\epsilon = (1/2)^N\,$ and for $n > N$ we have with the above Lemma: $\,\left|X(n)-x_1\right| < (1/2)^n < \epsilon$ . This completes the proof.
*Disclaimer*: though apart from a few technicalities perhaps, see the above *Note*.