# Find the value of $\sqrt{4+\sqrt[3]{4+\sqrt[4]{4+\sqrt[5]{4+ ....... }}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have tried solving this question. It would be great if someone gives some idea about how to go about solving this question.

Comment: 2.401615526026297355671587971656109034016639552161016527027633818278874921157513254553304977301472975629176075585565071836891089801877839776658934761375622082021212395176704512873346502372092553984611...

Comment: Define: $$a_n=\sqrt{4+\sqrt[3]{4+\sqrt[4]{4+\sqrt[5]{4+ .......\sqrt[n]{4} }}}}$$ and determine the limit of this sequence!!

Answer (score 3):

**Two long comment**, this question is related to other question, but it seems that there is no closed form from thier realively partiel answers:

- [Evaluating the sum $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[2]{2+\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt[4]{2+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{2}}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837189/evaluating-the-sum-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt22-sqrt32-sqrt42-cdots-s?lq=1)
- [Problem 6 - IMO 1985](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759599/problem-6-imo-1985)
- [How to find this limit: $A=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}}}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/576110/how-to-find-this-limit-a-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt1-sqrt-frac12-sqrt-fr)
- [Find the limit $L=\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n}}}}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/582196/find-the-limit-l-lim-n-to-infty-sqrt-frac12-sqrt3-frac13-cdo)

Comment: Nice links. Thanks.